# reg ex pattern @ + word, excluding case if @@ before word

Tags: python, regex

I'm currently facing a few cases I'm struggling with regex.

In my case, I'm using in python to replace matched patterns by other string available in a dict like this:

```
re.sub(r"@(\w+)", lambda m: my_dict[m.group(1)], my_string)
```

What I do now:

```
pattern = "@(\w+)"
```

to match entire word after "@". For instance "foo@bar foo2" matches only "bar"

1. I would like to add an "escape" sign, i.e if I have @@, it doesn't consider the word after.
   Therefore "foo@@bar foo2" shouldn't match anything.

How can I do so ?

2. Additionnally, how can I do to match whole word, and the next word(s) if and only if they are separated by a "."

For instance, matching "foo@bar.foo2.foo3 foo4" should match "bar.foo2.foo3".

Thank you

Comment: 1. `"(?:[^@]|^)@(\w+)"`
2. `"(?:[^@]|^)@([\w\.]+)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. ('Escape symbol')

Use a negative lookbehind:

```
(?<!@)@(\w+)
```

2. (words separated by periods)

Match a word immediately followed by an arbitrary number of words prefixed with a period:

```
(\w+(\.\w+)*)
```

Wrapped into a single regex:

```
(?<!@)@(\w+(\.\w+)*)
```

Demo [here (Regex101)](https://regex101.com/r/2zyIzF/2).

Comment: or `(?<!@)@((\w+\.?)+)`

Comment: @Dan That would allow for matches ending in a period, eg `foo.` in `@foo. bar`.